# Recursive Database design approach

Tags: database

I'm just teaching myself databases, and I'm trying to model an existing problem in  relational form. It's a bit messy, but simplified:
I have one `Foo` table, which contains lots of `Foos`, and each Foo has a one to many link to lots of `Bars` through `BarID`. Trouble is, one Bar might also have a one to many relationship to lots of other Bars, and I can't think how to model this and avoid nasty queries. Any advise welcome.

```
Foo [ FooID   …   BarID ]

Bar [  BarID   …   OtherBars??]
```

Comment: If you'll find *real* entities (which make sense) to work with instead of "foo" and "bar" - it'll be easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can have tables like this:

```
FooMaster[FooId, and other foo cols but no barid]
FooBarRel[Fooid, Barid]
BarMaster[Barid, and other bar details but no barid of other bars]
BarBarRel[Barid, RelBarid]
```

Comment: I just renamed ur table foo to FooMaster to make it more obvisious as master data where each fooid are unique.  FooBarRel table can have same FooId multiple times in rows with different barid i.e. combination of fooid and barid in this table would be unique. Similar approach for BarMaster and BarBarRel table. If u need any help in writing query for the same...let me know. but i believe this is the simplest and non messy approach for ur db design

Comment: Just followed your advice, and all is working fine. Thanks very much!